# Loop skips lines when reading data from a file into array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, loops, fstream

I'm working on a project for my CS 1 class where we have to make a function that reads data from a file into an array. However when it runs it only reads in every other line of data.

The file contains 22 3 14 8 12 and the output I get: 3 8 12

Any help is very appreciated. Sorry if this has already been answered, I couldn't find it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int readin();

int main() {
  readin();
  return 0;
}

int readin(){
  ifstream inFile;
  int n = 0;
  int arr[200];

  inFile.open("data.txt");

  while(inFile >> arr[n]){
    inFile >> arr[n];
    n++;
  }

  inFile.close();

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << arr[i] << " " << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: `inFile.open` not `File`.

Comment: `readin()` must return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are reading from your file stream in your conditional query:

```
while(inFile >> arr[n]) // reads the first element in the file
```

and then reading it again and *rewriting* this value inside the loop:

```
{
    inFile >> arr[n];  // reads the next element in the file, puts it in the same place
    n++;
}
```

Just do:

```
while(inFile >> arr[n]) n++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like this:

```
while(inFile >> arr[n]){
    n++;
}
```

But what if the number of values in the file is greater than the array size?
Then you are facing an `undefined behavior`.

- I recommend using `vectors`:

  ```
  std::vector<int> vecInt;
  int value;

  while(inFile >> value)
     vecInt.push_back(value);

  for(int i(0); i < vecInt.size(); i++)
      std::cout << vecInt[i] << std::endl;
  ```